# SQL Oracle find substring in larger string

Tags: sql, oracle

I got this little sql-statement:

```
select 
NVL(table2.usermail, 'some other mail') user_mail
from 
table1, table2 
where table1.user = table2.usernr
```

This works pretty fine but the result isnt the one I need.

Example:

`table1.user` gives me "KNL\MarkZuckerbeg"
`table2.usernr` gives me "MarkZuckerbeg"

`table1.user = table2.usernr` now is the reason I dont get data back.

Any ideas how to solve this?

I tried using INSTR with no results.

Comment: there is also a regexp_like if you need use some regular expressions in your match.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like` instead:

```
select coalesce(t2.usermail, 'some other mail') as user_mail
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.user like '%' || t2.usernr || '%';
```

Note other changes:

- Explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Table aliases, which make the query easier to write and to read.
- `COALESCE()` instead of `NVL()`.  `COALESCE()` is the ANSI standard function and more flexibly (it can take more than two arguments).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSTR` if you wish to:

```
SELECT NVL(TABLE2.USERMAIL, 'some other mail') USER_MAIL
  FROM TABLE2
  INNER JOIN TABLE1
    ON INSTR(TABLE1.USER, TABLE2.USERNR) > 0 OR
       INSTR(TABLE2.USERNR, TABLE1.USER) > 0
```

Best of luck.